# UIWebView content resizing on device rotation

Tags: uiwebview, rotation, resize

I'm using a UIWebView in my application to show some information to the user. Everything works fine when rotating the Simulator: the objects are resizing just fine, as I would expect.

The only problem is the UIWebView that, although it seems to resize correctly (the frame, in fact, does resize well), keeps shrinking its content by 1px at each rotation.

The more I rotate the device, the more a black column grows at the right side of the UIWebView.

Fixes that I've tried and that haven't worked:

- calling setScalesPageToFit: YES on the UIWebView;
- setting the viewport meta tag;
- setting the content mode of the UIWebView;
- calling [myWebView reload];
- reloading the HTML after setting UIWebView's frame size

This is not a severe problem for me, but it's rather annoying. Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance.
Luca